# Low Variables aren't displaying in the Matrix dropdown

Tags: matrix, low-variables

This is the second site I've had this problem on, but when I set a matrix field to low variables, I set the grouping I want, add a low variable to that group, but when I go to the entry, the dropdown in matrix is empty.

Using:

- EE 2.5.5,
- Low Variables 2.3.4
- Matrix 2.5.3

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of your Matrix/LV setup and add some example template code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quote [the docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/fieldtype):

> Please note that only *non-hidden* and variables with *early parsing
>   disabled* show up in the variable list in the Publish Form.

This goes for Matrix fields as well. Make sure the variables you want to select from aren't hidden nor have early parsing enabled.

Comment: Missed that bit about the early parsing disabled. Thanks!